Multiple Fetches to count records from Core Data
I just want to share that I have a Core Data app with the following:

Each of them is a button where user can press to filter out the data for example (left to right): All, Inbox, Archive, More, Good, Evil, Important. You will also note that each of this button has a counter.
In my ViewModel, I have a function to count each of them, which is called when in the app's onAppear()
func countItem() -> (countTotal: Int, countArchive: Int, countGood: Int, countEvil: Int, countImportant: Int) {
    let request: NSFetchRequest<ThoughtEntity> = ThoughtEntity.fetchRequest()
    
    request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "thoughts != %@", "")
    let items1 = (try? manager.container.viewContext.fetch(request)) ?? []
    let countTotalPredicate = items1.count
    
    request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "isArchive == true")
    let items2 = (try? manager.container.viewContext.fetch(request)) ?? []
    let countArchivePredicate = items2.count
    
    request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "type CONTAINS %@", "good")
    let items3 = (try? manager.container.viewContext.fetch(request)) ?? []
    let countGoodPredicate = items3.count
    
    request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "type CONTAINS %@", "evil")
    let items4 = (try? manager.container.viewContext.fetch(request)) ?? []
    let countEvilPredicate = items4.count
    
    request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "type CONTAINS %@", "important")
    let items5 = (try? manager.container.viewContext.fetch(request)) ?? []
    let countImportantPredicate = items5.count

    return (countTotalPredicate, countArchivePredicate, countGoodPredicate, countEvilPredicate, countImportantPredicate)
}

The code works well enough.
I am wondering is there a better way to do it instead of fetching it from the database 5 times? Perhaps the "cost" of fetching is low, so it doesn't matter but I am wondering if there is a better, more efficient way of doing it?

You can use the count(for:) method on the viewContext to return just the count, not all of the entities.
let request: NSFetchRequest<ThoughtEntity> = ThoughtEntity.fetchRequest()
        
request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "thoughts != %@", "")
let countTotalPredicate = try? manager.container.viewContext.count(for: request)) ?? 0


Thanks. That's a good tip. But I still need to do it 5 times, right?

Well you do want five different counts with five different predicates, unless I’m misunderstanding your requirements. Using the count method forces Core Data to do less heavy lifting and it’s five less lines of code.

Yes, you understand my requirement correctly. Thank you.

This approach saves having to instantiate all of those objects just to count them. If your predicates return a lot of objects, time/memory savings can be substantial.

You could use NSExpression and a count method for the 3 predicates using the  type attribute but I think you need to do the other two separately
Something like this
let request = NSFetchRequest<NSDictionary>(entityName: "ThoughtEntity")
request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \ThoughtEntity.type, ascending: false)]
let predicate = NSCompoundPredicate(orPredicateWithSubpredicates: [
    NSPredicate(format: "type CONTAINS %@", "good"), 
    NSPredicate(format: "type CONTAINS %@", "evil"),
    NSPredicate(format: "type CONTAINS %@", "important")
]

request.predicate = predicate

let keyPath = NSExpression(forKeyPath: "type")
let expression = NSExpression(forFunction: "count:", arguments: [keyPath])
let countDescription = NSExpressionDescription()
countDescription.expression = expression
countDescription.name = "count"
countDescription.expressionResultType = .integer64AttributeType

request.propertiesToGroupBy = ["type"]
request.propertiesToFetch = ["type", countDescription]
request.resultType = .dictionaryResultType


Note though that if the entity doesn't contain to many objects it might be faster to fetch all in one request and then do the counting in memory since even with this solution you would need to execute 3 requests.

Maybe the predicate can be improved to use something like sql IN (...)

I appreciate your answer, Joakim. While I am going to go with Magnas' response because I understand the code, I will also study yours for my learning. Thank you.

No problem, the other answer is more straightforward but I still wanted to show this alternative.
